# 010 editor templates - partially initialize structure

Tags: templates, binary

Is there way to define some struct in 010 Editor template that will be only partially initialized and initializing of some parameters will be finished later. I've found that I can create another structure like `MeshUvData(Mesh &mesh)` that will be initialized somehow as `MeshUvData(mesh[i])` but I'm looking for more readable to keep the data in 1 `struct`.

Example:

```c
struct Mesh {
    float num_verts;
    float coords[num_verts*3];
    float uv[num_verts*2];
};

uint num_meshes;
uint num_textures;

// here need to initialize everything besides `uv` parameter
Mesh meshes[num_meshes];
Texture textures[num_textures];

// here need to finish initializng just `uv` attribute
Mesh meshes[num_meshes];
```